# Every short exact sequence splits implies object is projective?

Tags: homological-algebra, abelian-categories

It's known that a module P is projective if and only if every short exact $0\rightarrow M\rightarrow N \rightarrow P\rightarrow 0$ splits, and I'm wondering if this holds true for general Abelian categories.

P is projective implies the sequence splits is obvious. For the converse, I tried to substitute N's with direct sums involving P, but got stucked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Do you have in hands the concept of pullback in a category? Consider a diagram 
$$\begin{array}
& &&p\\
&&\downarrow\\
a & \rightarrow & b&\rightarrow &0
\end{array}$$
in an abelian category. Let
$$\begin{array}
&c & \xrightarrow{f} & p & \rightarrow & 0
\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow
\\
a & \rightarrow & b & \rightarrow & 0\end{array}$$

be the pullback of the initial diagram. Therefore there exists exact sequence $0\rightarrow k\rightarrow c\xrightarrow{f}p\rightarrow0$ so it splits. Let $g$ an arrow (morphism) such that $f\circ g=1_p$. It is clear that $p\xrightarrow{g}c\rightarrow a$ factors $p\rightarrow b$ as desired.